# C++ multiple inheritance method overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base1 {
public:
    virtual void f(int n) = 0;
};

class Base2 {
public:
    virtual void f(char *s) = 0;
};

class Derive1 : public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
    void f(int n) { cout << "d1 fn" << endl; }
    void f(char *s) { cout << "d1 fs" << endl; }
};

class Derive2 : public Derive1 {
public:
    void f(int n) { cout << "d2 fn" << endl; }
    void f(char *s) { cout << "d2 fs" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Derive1 *d1 = new Derive2();
    int n = 0;
    char *s = "";
    d1->f(n);
    d1->f(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs as expected, but if I comment out one method of Derive1, I got conversion error; if I comment out both methods of Derive1, I got methods ambiguity error.

What confused me is that why Derive1 has to define these two methods, why defining them only in Derive2 is not working. I need some help to understand this.

Some clarifications:

1. Let's suppose I never want to create any instances of Derive1. So, it is totally okay if Derive1 is an abstract class.
2. "All pure virtual functions should have a definition in derived class." This is not true if I don't want to create instances of this derived class.
3. If I change f in Base1 to f1, and f in Base2 to f2(just change names), then Derive1 does not need to define any of them, just defining f1 and f2 in Derive2 works.

So, with the support of method overloading, I thought, in the above code, I declared a function with the name like f_int in Base1; in Base2 I declared a function with the name like f_str. This is the way how the compiler implements method overloading, right? But it seems like this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

`Derive1` is a derived class from `Base1` and `Base2`. Derived classes **must** implement all *pure* virtual functions of their base classes.

It doesn't help `Derive1` that `Derive2` implements these functions, because it is possible to instantiate a `Derive1`, and to do so it must implement all inherited pure virtual methods.

For example, if you did not implement the functions in `Derive1`, what would you expect the behavior of this to be?

```
Derive1* d1 = new Derive1;
int n = 0;
char *s = "";
d1->f(n);
d1->f(s);
```

`Derive1` didn't implement these, and `d1` isn't a `Derive2` instance, so what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Derived classes must implement all **pure** virtual functions.

Comment: Thanks, I've added this clarification to my post.

Comment: *Concrete* classes must implement all pure virtual methods from their base class(es). An intermediate abstract class need not. That's not the problem in this case though.

Comment: Let's suppose I never want to create any instances of Derive1, I still need to define all the pure virtual functions that Derive1 inherited?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a pure virtual function in a class, it will turned to become an abstract class and you can't instantiate that one. And all pure virtual functions should have a definition in derived class. Your both base classes has pure virtual functions and so your derived1 should define the pure virtual functions of base classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with removing both in `Derived1`:

When you call `d1->f`, you haven't created any specific to that class, so it looks to its base classes. Each base class would be treated as a separate set of candidates. So first it checks base1 and see an `f`, then checks base2 and sees another `f`. The compiler can't pick which one to call, so the call is ambiguous. You can `using` the parent functions into `Derived1` if you don't want to re-implement them, or give the compiler a hint about which base to use.

If you only comment out one of the functions in `Derived1`, the one you you leave *hides* both parent versions, preventing either one of them from being selected. At this point you can call the one you've defined and cannot call the other one, unless you again tell the compiler which specific base class you want to call it from.

Comment: With the support of method overloading, I think when checking Base1, the compiler should see something like f_int; when checking Base2, the complier should see something like f_str. So these two f functions are kind of two different functions, then why one will hides the other?